# Using specific CLDR version without updating Java version

Tags: java, date, time, java-17, cldr

[Java 15](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15all-relnotes.html) uses version [37 of CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-37)(Common Locale Data Repository), as for [Java 17](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17all-relnotes.html) - it uses the latest ([v39](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-39)). Is there any way I can set java to use the latest cldr version without needing to upgrade the java version, e.g replacing the CLDR version bundled with the JDK?
I can't manually setup CLDR data in my project as the internal java classes (java.time.*) use the CLDR version associated with the java version. Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace the CLDR bundled in a JDK? Your question is not clear. What exactly is your problem? What exactly do you want as a solution?

Comment: Yes, if possible at all.

Comment: I suggest your edit your Question for clarity.